# Accessing an object's attributes correctly out of a vector and clearing it out

Tags: c++, vector

I'm unfamiliar with OO in C++.

I've been pushing instances of the `MyPoint` class into

```
vector <MyPoint> trianglePoints;
```

like this:

```
trianglePoints.push_back(MyPoint(x,y));
```

This is my definition of MyPoint:

```
class MyPoint {

public:
    float x; 
    float y;

    MyPoint(float x, float y) //constructor
    {
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;

    }

}; //end
```

After pushing three points into the vector I call a function to render the triangle and then do:

```
trianglePoints.clear();
```

**Questions:**

a) How do I get my three x,y coordinates from the vector? I want to store each into its own int xi,yi to render them.

b) Is it okay to call `clear()` on the vector even though I haven't defined a destructor for the MyPoint class?

Comment: If you don't have one, make sure you get [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list); it will help to answer this sort of question for you.

Comment: @James: You sound like me now, in this regard. :) Good, I was getting tired of being the one saying "get a book". :P

Comment: I think asking in SO is way faster (and more educational and thought-clarifying) than going through a book.

Comment: @omgzor: Ha, no. You'll never learn it properly if you scrap for bits of information online. Also, use an initialization list.

Comment: @GMan:  Heh.  Well, now that we don't have Mr. Butterworth to keep the beginners in line, I figure we all have to help out as much as we can :-D

Comment: @James: Yeah, it'll take 2 or 3 of us to equal up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

```
trianglePoints[0].x
trianglePoints[0].y
trianglePoints[1].x
trianglePoints[1].y
trianglePoints[2].x
trianglePoints[2].y
```

b)

Yes, the class uses the default destructor.

Answer (score 2):

(a) You can get elements from the vector using array syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    do_something(trianglePoints[i]);
}
```

or iterator syntax:

```
for (std::vector<MyPoint>::iterator it = trianglePoints.begin();
     it != trianglePoints.end(); ++it)
{
    do_something(*it);
}
```

or using algorithm syntax:

```
std::for_each(trianglePoints.begin(), trianglePoints.end(); do_something);
```

For more details on what you can do with `std::vector`, see e.g. http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/.

(b) It's ok to call clear; explicit destructors are only necessary if you have resources to clear up (like memory, file handles, etc.), or if your class is a base class (in which case you may need a virtual destructor).

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get my three x,y coordinates from the vector?

`vector` overloads the subscript operator (`[]`), so elements can be accessed as if they are in an array.  Alternatively (and preferably), you can use iterators.

> Is it okay to call `clear()` on the vector even though I haven't defined a destructor for the MyPoint class?

Yes; the compiler provides a default destructor.